# html5 making the time stepper bigger

Tags: css, html

I've been playing with the different types in html for the app I'm making. However, I'm making this app for touch screen computers so I a wondering if the 'stepper' that appears when it is either a `type="time"` or `type="date"` can be made larger so it is easier to press. Right now it is quite hard with big fingers and I can't find anything on google.

the html looks like this

```
<input type='time' value='' />
```

And a picture of what it ends up looking like.
[image: time input]

Any help would be great!